# Internet explorer 11 - unable to re-import a certificate after deleting

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer, certificate, internet-explorer-11

Situation:

I am logged in as a user with admin privileges on my Windows 10 10 Pro DELL laptop.

I have installed a certificate, and it normally appeared in the certificate manager and IE11, and it worked for client access authorization to a website.

For troubleshooting, I removed it by deleting it by going through Internet Options > Content > Certificates > Personal.

I need to add the certificate back as I need it for access authorization to a website.

Problem:

When I install certificate again. I receive `installation/import successful`. However, the certificate does not appear in the *Personal* section, only in the *Other people* section. The access to the website that worked before is denied now.

I tried importing it several times. I tried copying it manually with certificate manager into the personal section.

The certificate now never appears in the personal section, and access to the website does not work anymore

Question:

What am I missing? How to fix this?

Comment: Use MMC, add/remove snap-in and select certificate manager, BUT set the target as Local Computer. Import into the appropriate store. Certmgr.msc is always current user. Also, certlm.msc can be used for local machine.

Comment: You can drag and drop the certificate to the correct store or import it directly to the correct store (instead of allowing Windows to determine that).  It’s very likely the certificate has expired, which doesn’t make it an unsafe certificate but would explain the behavior you describe

Comment: @Ramhound -the certificate is not expired. and like I said. Certificate manager shows the certificates in both directories

Comment: @ spikey. thank you for the tip. still nothing. now i have the certificate also under Local Computer. Internet Explorer still does not show the Client Authentication certificate under Personal and access is denied.

Comment: @pcihy - I honestly couldn’t tell you the impact of having a certificate in the same certificate store twice.  I would drag and drop the certificate manually.